Visual Studio 2022 "Find and Replace" style setting?
Visual Studio 2022 Find and Replace window style went wrong
The screenshot here:

How can I fix it to the left one?
So I need to add more line or StackOverflow won't let me post.
So I need to add more line or StackOverflow won't let me post.
So I need to add more line or StackOverflow won't let me post.

With a proper name scheme, you don't have to remember all the instances of certain identifiers (macros & variable names) throughout the files of a project. Find & replace is your handy tool. You don't need an eidetic memory.

Please click the menu "List View" to toggle the layout of the Find Results window to see if the window behaves as expected.
Test Result:

